# how could I define (optimize) a calculated member without using 'WHEN CASE' when it is a linear calculation?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

I am performing a calculation where it defines the day number of an event. Ex: 2022-02-13 -> day 1, 2022-02-14 -> day 2, etc. I have made this calculation but in a non-optimal way:

```
WITH MEMBER CurrentDay As 
CASE
WHEN Format(Now(),'yyyy-MM-dd')  = '2022-02-13' THEN 1
WHEN Format(Now(),'yyyy-MM-dd')  = '2022-02-14' THEN 2
WHEN Format(Now(),'yyyy-MM-dd')  = '2022-02-15' THEN 3
//ETC
END

Select CurrentDay on 0 from
[Cube]
```

Is there a way to optimize this code?

currently in the cube the time dimension is not contemplated so I do not have how to relate it (the measure of time is the day number)

Answer (score 1):

I think `DATEDIFF('d', '2022-02-13', NOW()) + 1` should give you the expected result.

Comment: It worked fine except for the first parameter. Instead of day I put 'd' and it worked fine. Thanks a lot!